# Join mysql table on duplicate values

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables `countries_ship` and `countries`

countries

```
id  country_code country_name
1   US           United States
2   CA           Canada
```

countries_ship (this table has no primary key)

```
item_id country_id
143     1
143     2
```

If viewing item with id 143, I want to show that the item can be shipped to the US and CA. The query below is as far as I got with this ... and it's just wrong.

```
$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT cs.item_id, cs.country_id, c.country_code 
                                 FROM 
                                   cs.countries_ship 
                                 JOIN 
                                   countries c ON cs.country_id=c.id 
                                 WHERE item_id = $itemID");
```

Comment: For what stands the `c` in your join statement?

Comment: For the countries table ... ?

Comment: You have `countries` already, you don't have to write a `c` again!

Comment: @Rizier123 that is just an `AS` alias for a table. I don't understand your criticism. Aliases are always only there for convenience; you don't ever **need** them.

Comment: why are you saying the sql statement is just wrong ? it should return you 2 rows each with the country code you want, its not the best sql statement but i think it does what you want ?

Comment: "and it's just wrong." : Maybe you could be more specific? What is it doing compared to what you expect?

Comment: Sorry, it's returning `Call to a member function execute() on a non-object` as it is now.

Comment: "FROM cs.countries_ship" should be "FROM countries_ship cs"

Answer (score 1):

I believe that this should work!
I'm doing a join of c with cs creating a table with:

cs.item_id ,  cs_country_id ,c.country_code

Then i'm only selecting the lines where cs.item_id are the ones you are looking for.

```
$q = $this->db->mysqli->prepare("SELECT cs.item_id, cs.country_id, c.country_code 
                             FROM 
                               c , cs 
                               WHERE cs.country_id = c.id
                               AND cs.item_id = $itemID

                             );
```

Comment: Makes sense. But still returning `Fatal error: Call to a member function execute() on a non-object`

Comment: There's probabiliy some error in the query ... try this:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: You need to alter the query portion "FROM c, cs" so that it is clear what the aliases are.  Try instead "FROM countries c, countries cs"

Comment: @SharonLevy probabily better to use "FROM countries_ship , countries" and also "SELECT countries_ship.item_id , countries_ship.country_id , countries.country_code" then

Comment: It's perfectly fine and normal to use aliases.  I just now tweaked my query above so as to include them when selecting fields from the two tables.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is the query you need:

SELECT cs.item_id, c.country_name FROM countries c, countries_ship cs WHERE c.id = cs.country_id and cs.item_id = 143

Note: that the comma operator creates the join for you based on the specified conditions.

This is the PHP you may wish to try since it doesn't seem like in this case that a prepared statement is warranted (see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php):

```
<?php
$itemID = 143;
$sql = "SELECT cs.item_id, c.country_name " . 
       "FROM countries c, countries_ship cs " . 
       "WHERE c.id = cs.country_id and cs.item_id = $itemID";
$res = $mysqli->query( $sql );
$fetched = $res->fetch_all( MYSQLI_ASSOC );

// if one wishes to view what was fetched:
foreach ( $fetched as $record ) {
    echo $record['item_id'], ' ', $record['country_name'],"<br>\n";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could just make one single table that has id, item_id, country_code and country_name and make a query like this:

have a page with a get variable in the url like id.

```
<?php $id = $_GET['id']; //this will be the itemid. ?>
```

select all country_codes or country_names that have this id for example,

```
<?php
  $get_countrys = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM countries WHERE item_id='$id' ");
  while($country = mysql_fetch_assoc($get_countrys)){
     $countryCode = $country['country_code'];
     echo $countryCode;
  }
?>
```

Comment: @Pickering MySQL has been officially deprecated as of PHP5.5; see http://php.net/manual/en/migration55.deprecated.php

Comment: I know that, it's just I still PHP 5.2 I think it is sorry for my misunderstanding of the PHP version.